# Getting index out of bound because the selected index item number is the same last item number in a list. how to solve it?

Tags: c#, winforms

At the top of form1:

```
BindingList<MyListBoxItem> MyItems { get; } = new BindingList<MyListBoxItem>();
```

The class MyListBoxItem:

```
public class MyListBoxItem
        {
            public Color ItemColor { get; set; }
            public string Message { get; set; }
        }
```

The selectedindex code event:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var tt = MyItems.ToList();
            var si = tt[listBox1.SelectedIndex].Message;
            var val = si;
            int index = val.LastIndexOf(",");
            string you = val.Substring(index + 1);
            if (File.Exists(you))
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(you);
            }
        }
```

but getting exception on the line:

```
var si = tt[listBox1.SelectedIndex].Message;
```

because the selectedindex is 6 and tt contains 6 items.

I tried to make:

```
var si = tt[listBox1.SelectedIndex  - 1].Message;
```

but then if the selectedindex is 0 the same exception happens.

I'm using the mouse to draw rectangles over a pictureBox image and when stop drawing it's getting to the mouseup event and then to the listbox! selectedindexchanged event and then the selected index is the same number as the items in MyItems:

```
int count = 0;
        private void pictureBox2_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left || crop == false) return;

            if (DrawingRects.Count > 0 && pictureBox2.Image != null && selectedPath != "")
            {
                if ((x >= 0 && x <= pictureBox2.Image.Size.Width) && (y >= 0 && y <= pictureBox2.Image.Size.Height))
                {
                    var dr = DrawingRects.Last();
                    if (dr.Rect.Width > 0 && dr.Rect.Height > 0)
                    {
                        rectImage = cropAtRect((Bitmap)pictureBox2.Image, dr.Rect);

                        if (saveRectangles)
                        {
                            count++;
                            rectangleName = GetNextName(Path.Combine(selectedPath, "Rectangle"), ".bmp");
                            FileList.Add($"{dr.Location}, {dr.Size}", rectangleName);
                            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
        FileList,
        Formatting.Indented
    );
                            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(selectedPath, "rectangles.txt"), false))
                            {
                                sw.WriteLine("Total number of rectangles: " + count + Environment.NewLine);
                                sw.Write(json);
                                sw.Close();
                            }

                            rectImage.Save(rectangleName);
                            saveRectanglesCounter++;  
                           
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var stream = ToMemoryStream(rectImage);
                            var image  = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
                            pictureBox1.Image = image;
                        }
                        
                        pixelsCounter = rect.Width * rect.Height;
                        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
                        listBox1.DataSource = FileList.Keys.ToList();
                        listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - 1;

                        pictureBox2.Focus();
                        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(this.pictureBox1.Image);
                        g.Clear(this.pictureBox1.BackColor);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (clearRectangles)
                    {
                        DrawingRects.Clear();
                        pictureBox2.Invalidate();
                    }

                    x = 0;
                    y = 0;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you have more items in the `ListBox` than in the `MyItems`?

Comment: This piece of code looks right, it must be a problem from somewhere else. you can use `listBox1.SelectedItem as MyListBoxItem` instead of finding selected object from the list by selected index.

Comment: @Fabio i'm using the mouse to draw rectangles over a pictureBox image and in the mouseup event after that event it's getting to the listBox1 selectedindex event and then the index is 8. I will update my question with the mouseup code.

Comment: @Fabio I see now that in the MouseUp event i'm making this line: listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - 1; can't remember why I did it but maybe this cause the problem in the selectedindex event ?